# Android Fragment does not Implement Activity's Interface error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface, fragment

My activity (NewTaskInput) declares an interface OnFABClickedListener with one method called onFABClicked that requires the NewTaskInputFragment fragment class to implement it in the activity's onFragmentAttached method. My fragment does implement the interface and the method onFABClicked that returns a Parcelable POJO (TaskItem) back to the activity.

However I get the error message that the fragment is not implenting the interface? Error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ReportFragment{d8395ee #0
>   android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag} must
>   implement OnFABClickedListener at  ...
>   activities.NewTaskInput.onAttachFragment(NewTaskInput.java:48)

Any idea why I get the error?

**NewTask.java (activity)**

```
public class NewTaskInput extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Interface
    public interface OnFABClickedListener {
        TaskItem onFABClicked();
    }

    // Member variables
    private OnFABClickedListener fabClickedListener;
    private TaskItem mTaskItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task_input);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTaskItem = fabClickedListener.onFABClicked();
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        try {
            fabClickedListener = (OnFABClickedListener)fragment;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString() + " must implement OnFABClickedListener");
        }
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        fabClickedListener = null;
    }
}
```

**NewTaskInputFragment.java**

```
public class NewTaskInputFragment extends Fragment implements NewTaskInput.OnFABClickedListener {
  .
  .
  .

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context activtiy) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity)activtiy;
        super.onAttach(activtiy);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newtask_input, container, false);

        initializeViews(rootView);
        initializeListeners();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskItem onFABClicked() {

        // Initialize a new TaskItem instance
        mTaskItem = new TaskItem();

        mTaskItem.seTitle(editTask.getText().toString());

        return mTaskItem;
    }
```

activity_new_task_input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.NewTaskInput">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_new_task_input" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/save" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_new_task_input.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="....fragments.NewTaskInputFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_newtaskgoal_input" />
```

Comment: where is the code for attach fragment in Activity?

Comment: I add it using an <include.. /> tag  added: activity_new_task_input.xml and content_new_task_input.xml to my code above

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the error? :)

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: **ReportFragment**{d8395ee #0 android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher.report_fragment_tag} must implement OnFABClickedListener at ... activities.NewTaskInput.onAttachFragment(NewTaskInput.java:48)

It says the `ReportFragment` doesn't implement your `OnFABClickedListener` interface. You haven't included the code of this fragment but I suspect that the stack trace is not lying and the fragment indeed does not implement that interface.

`onAttachFragment` is called for any fragment that is attached to your activity, not only `NewTaskInputFragment`.

Comment: But nowhere have I even declared a Fragment called ReportFragment?

Comment: That I can't possibly know.. I think it would be simpler if you don't use `onAttachFragment` at all and just use `FragmentManager` to find your fragment either by id or by tag. Then you can call `onFABClicked` on it the same way that you do now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll rather do that then.